# Submitting a model class from view.py

Tags: python, django

Ive tried to submit a model class using a view function but the form didn't submitted.

This The model class inside models.py file :

```
class Campaign(models.Model):
    username = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    message = models.TextField()
    link = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    added= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and this its form inside forms.py :

```
class CampaignForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Campaign
        fields=('title','message')
```

Ive tried to submit this form using this function at views.py :

```
def Campaign(request):
    form = CampaignForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            submit= Campaign(username=request.user)
            submit.save()

    context={
    'form':form,
    }

    return render(request, 'campaigns.html',context)
```

And this is the html file :

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <form action="" method="POST" class="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit">
    </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do `action="#"` in your form html because some browsers can not accept empty action values.

Also you have a mistake in this part of code:

```
submit= Campaign(username=request.user)
submit.save()
```

You have to get the form values into your object, you can do it this way:

```
submit = form.save(commit=False)
submit.username = request.user
submit.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers will fail to post if the action attribute is empty, try with

```
<form action="." method="POST">
```

Notice the dot ".", since you are using the same view to display the form and process it the dot it's ok.